# How to I get a list of non subscribed users from this database?

Tags: db2

I have 2 tables.

1) subscription_types

```
 | type |
  'type1'
  'type2'
```

2) subscriptions

```
| user | sub_type | subscribed |
  'U1'   'type1'    'Y'
  'U1'   'type2'    'Y'
  'U2'   'type1'    'Y'
```

From this ERD you can see that user 'U2' does not have entry for subscription 'type2'. I'd like to have a report of users who do not have subscription record.

So far I have:

```
 select user, count(1) 
 from subscriptions 
 group by user
 having count(1) != (select count(1) from subscription_types);
```

Which gives me a list of users that do not have all subscriptions. But not which ones they are missing.

I've tried many different variations of join queries where the subscription_type is null, no luck.

I was hoping the following query would solve it but alas it did not

```
 select user, sub_type
 from subscriptions 
 group by user, sub_type
 having sub_type not in (select type from subscription_types);
```

Comment: Why do you need `subscriptions.subscribed` if the fact of subscription is represented well enough simply by the presence of a record in that table?

Comment: @mustaccio I didn't build the tables. Not sure why previous dev did it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want the cartesian product between users and subscription_types, minus the subscriptions:

```
select distinct s.user, st.subscription_types
from subscriptions s
cross join subscription_types st
except
select user, sub_type
from subscriptions
```

This can, of course, be expressed in other ways, but this is probably the most obvious one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
with 
  subscription_types (type) as 
(
  values
  'type1'
, 'type2'
)
, subscriptions (user, sub_type, subscribed) as 
( 
  values
  ('U1', 'type1', 'Y')
, ('U1', 'type2', 'Y')
, ('U2', 'type1', 'Y')
)
select u.user, t.type
from 
(
select distinct s.user 
from subscriptions s
) u, subscription_types t
where not exists (select 1 from subscriptions s where s.user=u.user and s.sub_type=t.type);
```

The idea is to get all User & Type combinations, and return only those which don't exist in `subscriptions`.